# dbus java library update on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, dbus, bluez

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. One of my projects uses dbus java library(http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/dbus/dbus.jar.zip) to connect Bluetooth devices to Ubuntu OS.

On Ubuntu 16.04, I am getting following exception:

```
  `java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cx/ath/matthew/unix/UnixSocket
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.Transport.connect(Transport.java:765)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.Transport.<init>(Transport.java:730)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusConnection.<init>(DBusConnection.java:159)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusConnection.getConnection(DBusConnection.java:142)`
```

I also noticed that bluez package name on Ubuntu 16.04 is changed to bluez from bluez-utils.

dbus java library was last updated on 2010-01-17. It may need an update with latest Ubuntu 16.04 bluez package(Not sure ??)

Please do share if you have any pointers regarding above issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a Git forked repo of original java library and it resolved this issue. 
https://github.com/cathive/dbus-java

Answer (score 0):

Some detective work was required. In my case I had a development machine where the jar file executed fine, and a server, where the execution failed.

First, which dependency is the problem? A jar file is missing.

By running 'java -verbose:class -jar JARFILENAME' on both machines, and comparing the output, I found out that the jvm used unix.jar and hexdump.jar located in

```
/usr/share/java/unix.jar
/usr/share/java/hexdump.jar
```

and not the once included by me. Guess a solution would have been to recompile the dbus-java.jar to use the ones locally, but instead I did a quick fix on the server and added links to the searched jars

```
ln -s /pathtomyunixdotjar/unix.jar /usr/share/java/unix.jar
ln -s /pathtomyunixdotjar/hexdump.jar /usr/share/java/hexdump.jar
```

Compiling and installing the libmatthew-java on the server would have solved the issue as well I imagine.